# Receive a number using the phone key tones

Tags: twilio

I am going to use Twilio API to dial and play audio over the phone.
I would like to know if when the audio message is over I can request the phone reciever to dial a number and to get it back from Twilio API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Sure, once the audio completed, you could prompt the user to press a key:

```
<Response>
    <Play>http://example.com/sounds.mp3</Play>
    <Gather action="/gohere/" numDigits="1">
        <Say>To continue press a key</Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

In this example I'm using the `<Gather>` verb to tell Twilio to start listening for the user to press a key on their phone.  When that happens Twilio will make a request to the URL in the *action* parameter.

This also has the advantage of allowing you to know if the entire audio file played, or if the user hung up in the middle of it.

Hope that helps.